# Magento Add to Cart Button Change to Add to Quote on some products

Tags: magento2, quote

Any information on adding **`"Add to Quote"`** option in **Magento2** website .. for bulk order is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add some more details about your question.Do you just want to change the label of the button or any other functionality?

Comment: yes only label on specefic products.  and on which quote is written there will be inquery box not purchase..

Answer (score 0):

Usually that's a B2B functionality (wont be easily). You will need to add a button beside add to cart, or add a check in attribute level that product is for add to cart or add to quote.

Then after add to quote  send ajax to custom controller, and this will add it in customer session. And at the end create a form to send all products added in quote.

You can also use some pre-developed modules like:

https://marketplace.magento.com/cart2quote-module-not2order.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/cart2quote-module-propoza.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to change the label for the button the below will work just fine. If you need to change the actual functionality of the button then that'll take a bit more effort.

So you're best bet is to probably create a custom attribute, let's call it `quote_item`, and set it to true on the products you want to display "Add to Quote" for.

Then create a new file at `app/design/frontend/<Theme Vendor>/<Theme Name>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if($_product->getData('quote_item')):?>
    <?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Quote');?>
<?php else:?>
    <?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```